# Matrix Creation Automation

Tags: r, matrix, automation

I have roughly 1000 matrices which are formatted like this:

```
01202
10000
22110
22210
22222
```

I need them to look like this:

```
matrix1 <- rbind(c(0,1,2,0,2),c(1,0,0,0,0),c(2,2,1,1,0),c(2,2,2,1,0),c(2,2,2,2,2))
```

Any suggestions for how I could get this done? Doing this all by hand would take forever.. Thanks!

Comment: Are the numbers always integers?

Answer (score 2):

Using `read.fwf` from `base R`

```
as.matrix(read.fwf(textConnection(str1), widths = rep(1, 5) ))
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
[1,]  0  1  2  0  2
[2,]  1  0  0  0  0
[3,]  2  2  1  1  0
[4,]  2  2  2  1  0
[5,]  2  2  2  2  2
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "01202
10000
22110
22210
22222"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are characters a one-liner can do it.

```r
x <- scan(text='01202
10000
22110
22210
22222
', what = character())
x
#> [1] "01202" "10000" "22110" "22210" "22222"

t(sapply(strsplit(x, ""), as.numeric))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    0    1    2    0    2
#> [2,]    1    0    0    0    0
#> [3,]    2    2    1    1    0
#> [4,]    2    2    2    1    0
#> [5,]    2    2    2    2    2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Rui.. But I have a list in R that looks like what I have pasted below and it goes on for page after page...  Is there a script you know of that would allow me to convert each number set into separate matrices? 
22000
00010
22200
22222

00001
22200
22222

21200
21210
22222

01202
10000
22110
22210
22222

02022
01201
22222

11001
02210
22222

01011
21110
22222

Comment: @LiamBrothers What do you mean by each number set? Are there blank lines in a data file, are all sets 4 numbers long? What is the pattern to follow?

Answer (score 1):

You could directly use:

```
read.table(text = gsub("", " ", x))
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  0  1  2  0  2
2  1  0  0  0  0
3  2  2  1  1  0
4  2  2  2  1  0
5  2  2  2  2  2
```

or if you want it in matrix form:

```
as.matrix(read.table(text = gsub("", " ", x)))
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
[1,]  0  1  2  0  2
[2,]  1  0  0  0  0
[3,]  2  2  1  1  0
[4,]  2  2  2  1  0
[5,]  2  2  2  2  2
```

`x` is one of the matrices you have